# Liferay upgrade from 6.0.6CE to 6.2CE

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am planning to upgrade my company's intranet from liferay 6.0.6CE to 6.2CE. I have done some research on it but I am still confused on API part. Will my custom portlets need only recompilation or would they need a complete rewriting. I am also concerned about my Theme and Exts. I have a lot of customization in my exts and my theme. What would be the best way to move ahead?
Also I have a NFS file server and SOLR search server configured with my current deployment. Need suggestions on that too.

Comment: Almost complete rewriting, believe me.

For instance themes base are changed a lot and document library API has changed a lot.

Comment: Even updating to 6.1 would be a giant step. If you don't have to - don't do it.

Comment: I have tried to convert the themes from Liferay6.06 to 6.2, But its totally UI changes, if you want to Migrate themes just forget Migration of themes, go with creating new themes...

Comment: Thanks guys. Any suggestions regarding the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard recently, that the [Migration Tool](https://www.liferay.com/radio/-/asset_publisher/Q7Ic/blog/radio-liferay-episode-38-alberto-chaparro-on-the-migration-tool-for-portlets-version-6-1-to-6-2/1339770?#portlet_101_INSTANCE_Q7Ic) (6.1 to 6.2) now also supports themes. It won't be pixel perfect though. Check what it can do for you.

There have been some APIs that changed. Contrary to the comments given to your question, I'd say "It depends": I don't know how much of Liferay's API you use or if you just add functionality on top. You'll have to find out for yourself. The migration tool might help you.

The things that have changed the most are: Themes (using Bootstrap, as of 6.2) and Document Library (now including ImageGallery, which was still available in 6.0). Migration of data should be smooth if you follow the documented upgrade path. Migration of your portlets and plugins will definitely require recompile (within the new plugins sdk or updated maven dependencies) and probably adaptation to some changed API calls. I've seen instances where this was simple, but I've also seen hard cases.

As there have been no more updates for 6.0 CE for quite a while, I'm recommending to upgrade though (other than @FeinesFabi in the comment). If you want to have a long-term stable platform that you don't need to maintain for yourself, EE would be the way to go (supported for ~7 years after release)

For ext changes, you'll have to be aware that there are no guarantees: Ext allows you to change the inner implementation of Liferay, and that's what nobody strives to keep stable, even in minor updates. If you're using ext, you'll always have to be aware of incompatible changes. Ext allows you to keep your changes out of the official sourcecode - so they're well isolated. It doesn't say anything about the underlying implementation to be stable. With great power (ext) comes great responsibility. Keep your ext as small as possible - whatever you can do outside of ext should be done outside and use the public API.

The basic upgrade path (for Liferay itself, not your plugins) is quite well documented in the [User's Guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/upgrading-liferay-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-18-en).